# How use ssh proxy to run deploy job in gitlab ci?

Tags: docker, ssh, deployment, proxy, gitlab-ci

I have a server in Iran and i want use gitlab ci to open an ssh tunnel  to my server.

But thanks to Google cloud services, gitlab can not see Iran IPs.

Is there any way to use a middle server out of iran to open a proxy tunnel from gitlab to my proxy server and from that to my Iran server, then use docker to pull an image from gitlab registery?

Consider Iran servers can't connect to gitlab an gitlab can not connect to Iran servers too.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also this is worked for me

```
deploy:
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://example.com
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    ## Install rsync to create mirror between runner and host.
    - apt-get install -y rsync
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode)
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_USER@"$SSH_HOST" 'ls -la && ssh user@host "cd ~/api && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d"'
```

I also described everything that i did in Farsi here:
https://virgol.io/@aminkt

Answer (score 4):

I have succeeded with such code

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install openssh-client curl -y


integration:
  stage: integration
  script:
    - mkdir ~/.ssh/
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh -fN -L 1029:localhost:1729 user@$HOST -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 2>&1
    - ssh -fN -L 9013:localhost:9713 user@$HOST -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 2>&1
```